# Take Distinct Value from MultiDimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Actually i got multidimensional array like following need to format it. Already wasted lots of time figuring out it but no success 
**$main**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [value] => 3D-English
            [t_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [value] => 2D-English
            [t_id] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [value] => 2D-English
            [t_id] => 3
        )

)
```

---

Want to format into this array , how it could be achieved using php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [value] => 3D-English
            [t_id] => 5
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [value] => 2D-English
            [t_id] => 5-3
        )

)
```

**Update: Tried this**

```
$tmp="";
foreach($main as $k =>$v)
{
       if($tmp==$v['id'])
       {
              $tmparr[$v['id']]= $v['id'];

           if($tmparr['value']=="")
           {
               $tmparr['value'] = $v['t_id'];
           }
           else
           {
               $tmparr['value']= $tmparr['value']."-".$v['t_id'];
           }

       }
      else
     {
       $tmp= $v['id'];
     }
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried? **We dont write your App for you** but we will help with specific coding issues.

Comment: Which column is supposed to be unique? `id` or `value`? I can't tell from your example.

Comment: @Barmar: t_id is unique

Answer (score 1):

Create an associative array keyed off the column that you want to be unique, which is `id`.

```
$results = array();
foreach ($main as $element) {
    if (!isset($results[$element['id']])) {
        $results[$element['id']] = $element;
    } else {
        $results[$element['id']]['t_id'] .= '-' . $element['t_id'];
    }
}
```

Then you can use `array_values` to turn the associative array into an ordinary array.

```
$results = array_values($results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map()` function for this.

```
$array = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $yourarrayinput)));
```

Comment: This will only work if he wants all the elements of the sub-array to be unique. But he only wants it to be unique based on the `value` column.